# Shall there be a chat room for discussing or requesting help with Stack Overflow Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, chat

Is there a chat to ask things about Stack Overflow Documentation along the way?

Going to https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and typing "documentation" in the search field reveals nothing relevant. Is it because of there is no such room or I just can't find it?

Comment: I though [my submission](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rust/9104/custom-derive-macros-1-1) was published (or on the way to be published) long ago, but only now realised that I need yet one more button click for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Join us!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta)

(If it's not clear, you were searching the *Stack Exchange* chat system and Documentation is only on *Stack Overflow* (for now). Why there are separate chat systems is [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264524/chat-stackoverflow-com-chat-stackexchange-com-rooms-tab-sitehost-stackover).)

Comment: How do I find this room using search? What sequence of clicks lead to it only from the knowledge that it exists somewhere in StackExchange? Why do I still get other StackOverflow-question-associated chat rooms that have "documentation" word in title?

Comment: @Vi. Searching for "documentation" on chat.stackoverflow.com (tab "all", mode "created") shows that room as 1st result to me.

Comment: @Siguza, Created a "redirect" from chat.stackexchange.com to chat.stackoverflow.com: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57217/documentation-public-beta . Is it a good idea?